# What causes background processes to interfere with pyautogui?

Tags: python, windows, pyautogui

I have a program that runs pyautogui to simulate clicks and keyboard inputs. I just discovered a problem though, where I had the apps: "Intel Driver and Support Assistant", and "HP Support Solutions" running in the background, and they were causing pyautogui to only work if my program was focused. I uninstalled those two apps, and now pyautogui works fine. I was wondering though, does anyone know what specifically caused those apps to interfere with pyautogui? I've found answers like, "the inputs from pyautogui were being intercepted or blocked" but I would like a more specific answer so I can troubleshoot and fix any future issues like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this article that might help you: [Intel® Arc™ Hotkeys Conflict with Other Application Hotkeys](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000092782/graphics.html)

If you happened to install this, it might be what's causing the conflict. From Intel's website:

> Resolution
>
> Presently there is no way to edit hotkeys for the Intel Arc control
> panel so below is a suggested workaround to stop Intel Arc control
> services that disable Intel Arc control hotkeys so that other
> application hot-keys can be used.
>
> Press (Win+R )
>
> Type msconfig -->Services
>
> Find Intel(R) Control panel services. Uncheck it.
>
> Apply Reboot.
>
> Select No when the UAC popup appears to start the Intel Arc control
> panel on the system.
>
> After reboot, Intel Arc control panel services will be stopped, so
> Intel Arc control hotkeys are disabled. If desired, users can restart
> the service to use the Intel Arc control panel.